# Random Variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed on the interval
$[−2, 2]$, and $Y = (X − 1)^2$.

$(a)$ Find the density function and the distribution function of $X$.

$(b)$ Find the distribution function and the density function of $Y$.

Comment: Sow us what you have tried: (a) is easy while (b) may require some thought.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/ attentively.

Comment: Related meta thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/what-is-ptwo-distinct-users-with-poor-mse-etiquette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave part a) for you, but I will point out that the  density function, $f_X$, for $X$ is zero outside the interval $[-2,2]$; after all, $X$ takes all its values in this interval.

Before tackling part b), it would be beneficial to first determine the values that $Y$ takes: Since $X$ takes values in $[-2,2]$ and since $Y=(X-1)^2$, it follows that $Y$ takes values in the interval $[1,9]$.

From this it follows that $f_Y(x)=0$ for $x\notin[1,9]$. From this it follows that $F_Y(a)=0$ for $a\le1$ and that $F_Y(a)=1$ for $a\ge 9$.

That was the easy part. Let's now find the value of $F_Y(a)$ for $a\in[1,9]$.
The idea is write the distribution function of $Y$ in terms of the distribution function of $X$:

We have, for $1\le a\le9$
$$\eqalign{
F_Y(a) &= P[\,Y\le a\,]\cr
&=P[\,(X-1)^2\le a\,] \cr
&= P [\,1-\sqrt a \le X\le 1+\sqrt a \,  ]\cr
&= P[\,X\le 1+\sqrt a\,]-P[\,X\le 1-\sqrt a\,]\cr
&=F_X(1+\sqrt a) -F_X(1-\sqrt a).
}
$$

Now you can write the distribution function of $Y$ explicitly:
$$
F_Y(a)=\cases{0,\vphantom{1\over2}   &$a\le1$\cr  F_X(1+\sqrt a) -F_X(1-\sqrt a),\vphantom{1\over2} &$1\le a\le 9$,\cr 1,\vphantom{1\over2} &$a\ge9$   }
$$

Of course, in the above, you'd replace  $F_X(1-\sqrt a) -F_X(1+\sqrt a)$ with what you obtain from the rule for $F_X$  (note here that $1-\sqrt a$ and $1+\sqrt a$ are in the interval $[-2,2]$).

So, that's $F_Y$.  How do you find $f_Y$? As it turns out, this is easy to do now (and is why you were asked to find the distribution function of $Y$ first) by the following result: in general, if $F$ is a distribution function of a continuous random variable, then its derivative gives the corresponding density function of that variable.
In our case we have
$$
f_Y(x)={d\over dx}F_Y(x).
$$
But before we apply this, let's recall  we already determined that $f_Y(x)$ is zero for $x$ outside the interval $[1,9]$.  For $x\in [1,9]$, we have, using the chain rule and the fact that ${d\over dx} F_X(x)=f_X(x)$,
$$\eqalign{
f_Y(x)={d\over dx}F_Y(x) 
&= {d\over dx}\bigl(F_X(1+\sqrt x) -F_X(1-\sqrt x)\bigr)\cr
&={1\over2\sqrt x} f_X(1+\sqrt x)    +{1\over2\sqrt x} f_X(1-\sqrt x).\cr
}
$$
So
$$
f_Y(x)=\cases{  {1\over2\sqrt x} f_X(1+\sqrt x)    +{1\over2\sqrt x} f_X(1-\sqrt x), &$1\le x\le9$,\cr  0,\vphantom{1\over2}&otherwise .  }
$$
(And of course you'll want to simplify this using the density of $X$.)